# Is my home network infected?

Tags: malware, web-browser, virus

Today, my family brought me a quite old laptop (it had Windows 7 Enterprise from around 2009). When I tried to turn it on, it was already complicated because I got a black screen with options, but the keyboard wouldn't let me choose the startup option and it even made a loud noise suddenly, so I turned it off and on a couple of times until it finally let me in. When I managed to get in, a folder would open by itself and the same letter would be typed repeatedly, so I figured the keyboard wasn't working and plugged in an external one. After that, everything was fine; I just had to change the year, month, and time to be able to browse Google. However, when I opened Mozilla Firefox, everything was in Russian. That's when I thought I had a virus, but searching on the internet from my phone to see if it was possible, it seemed more likely that it was just a language change, so I tried to change the language. After a while of trying (without success), I noticed that the search URL was http://yandex.ru, and I honestly don't know if that's bad in itself, but I know it meant I didn't have a secure connection, so I got tired and wanted to uninstall it directly. From there, the serious problem started! I closed the browser to search how to uninstall it, and it started reopening automatically many times and showing me alerts in Russian hahaha, so I turned off the computer by unplugging the charger directly (the battery doesn't work well, so as soon as I unplug it, it turns off). The thing is, I thought it was a harmless virus that just wanted to crash the computer, so I turned it back on and again the time and year were misconfigured, but the pop-ups didn't appear anymore. So I didn't touch Firefox again and just opened Google to download an antivirus that is compatible with that Windows, but it was clear that the computer was much slower. I waited for it to download, but the computer wouldn't let me install it (it said the installer wasn't responding), so I tried restarting it again, and that's when I got scared because when it started up, I got a system virus alert that disappeared almost instantly so I couldn't even read it, and it wouldn't let me access the network options or the things in the taskbar at the bottom right. I tried to shut it down manually, but it wouldn't load either, so I disconnected it directly and didn't turn it back on. I honestly don't care about the computer anymore, but what worries me is that my home network may have been accessed, and from there, they may access connected devices. Is that possible? What do you recommend I do?

Comment: This is a very hard to read wall of text. But from what I understand it is impossible to say from the provided information that your network is infected for sure but also impossible to say that it is not infected for sure.

Comment: What should you do? What you should do with every used computer: format and reinstall... As for "is my home network infected?" we can't possibly determine that.